# Cannot find hidden input control on row data bound event

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

Here is my aspx file content.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnUnload="UpdatePanel_Unload">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input id="hdnAID" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
                        OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound"
                        DataKeyNames="GeneralSettingID" EnableViewState="true">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <GridEditPopupMenu:GridEditPopupMenu ID="GridEditPopupMenu1" runat="server" currenttemplate="ItemTemplate" ShowDeleteLink="0" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <GridEditPopupMenu:GridEditPopupMenu ID="GridEditPopupMenu1" runat="server" currenttemplate="EditItemTemplate" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="GeneralSettingID" HeaderText="SettingNo" ReadOnly="true" />

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SettingName">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label25" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GeneralSettingName") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUpdateGeneralSettingName" onfocus="this.blur();" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GeneralSettingName") %>'
                                        Width="350px" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Values">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label23" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GeneralSettingValue") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUpdateGeneralSettingValue" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GeneralSettingValue") %>'
                                        Width="600px" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="6" />
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>    

                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company1">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GeneralSettingCompany") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUpdateGeneralSettingCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GeneralSettingCompany") %>'
                                        Width="100px" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="1" Enabled="false" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField> 

                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company2">                                     
                                 <ItemTemplate>                                         
                                    <asp:DropDownList  ID="drpCompanyList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpCompanyList_SelectedIndexChanged" DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="CompanyID"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    <input id="hdnCompanyId" type="hidden" value='<%# Eval("GeneralSettingCompany") %>' runat="server" />
                                </ItemTemplate>                                                                                                                  
                            </asp:TemplateField>                                
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Here is the .cs side .

```
private LMSDataAccess.LookupsDataContext LkpDC = new LMSDataAccess.LookupsDataContext(ConfigFile.DBConnStr);
private System.Collections.Generic.List<LMSDataAccess.GeneralSetting> GeneralSettingList = null;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    base.ModuleID = 27;

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request["AID"] != null)
            hdnAID.Value = Request["AID"];

        BindData();
    }
}

private void BindData()
{
    GeneralSettingList = LkpDC.GeneralSettingsGetAll(Common.NVLInt(hdnAID.Value),null).ToList();
    GridView1.DataSource = GeneralSettingList;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindData();
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtUpdateGeneralSettingName = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUpdateGeneralSettingName");
    TextBox txtUpdateGeneralSettingValue = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtUpdateGeneralSettingValue");
    var hdnCompany = (HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("hdnCompanyId") as HiddenField;

    string KeyValue = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

    LkpDC.GeneralSettingsUpdate(Convert.ToInt32(KeyValue),
        txtUpdateGeneralSettingName.Text,
        txtUpdateGeneralSettingValue.Text, 
        Convert.ToInt32(hdnCompany.Value));

    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindData();
    ResultCode = 0;
}

protected List<LMSDataAccess.Company> GetAllCompanies()
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<LMSDataAccess.Company> CompanyList = null;
    LMSDataAccess.OrganizationDataContext OrgDC = new LMSDataAccess.OrganizationDataContext(ConfigFile.DBConnStr);

    CompanyList = OrgDC.CompaniesGetAll(null).ToList();
    return CompanyList;
}
protected void drpCompanyList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;        
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.Parent.Parent;
    var hdnCompany = row.FindControl("hdnCompanyId") as HiddenField;
    hdnCompany.Value = ddl.SelectedValue;        
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender,GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var ddl = e.Row.FindControl("drpCompanyList") as DropDownList;
        //here is the problem.
        var hdn = e.Row.FindControl("hdnCompanyId") as HiddenField;

        if (ddl != null)
        {
            ddl.DataSource = GetAllCompanies();
            ddl.DataValueField = "CompanyID";
            ddl.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
            ddl.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

My beloved problem is not being able to get hdnCompanyId element when GridView1_RowDataBound and drpCompanyList_SelectedIndexChangedfired.I am always getting null.(as showed at the commented line )

I have tried under GridView1_RowDataBound event method like `e.Row.FindControl("hdnCompanyId")`
but it did not work.
My final aim is to setting and getting this element to control selected items of my dropdownlist.

I think the code is well written but I guess I am missing something about hierarchy of the user control elements.
Can you help me about what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem was choosing the wrong casting type of the input.It must be `HtmlInputHidden` rather than `HiddenField`.I hope someone can get useful info from that question.